# Zline range air adjustment

Tags: natural-gas, range

I have a Zline 6 burner gas range (natural gas).  The flames are a bit more yellow than I would like.  However, I can not find information on adjusting the air mixture, either in the manual or online.  Does anyone have any advice on this?
Zline RG36 Freestanding Gas Range.

Comment: Listing the exact brand/model # will help people find the instructions so they can help you. Of course, including a link to the instructions will make it even easier for someone to help you...

Comment: Might just need cleaning of the holes in the pipes, but this is something you should have checked by a gas installer.  It can be dangerous if CO gas builds up enough and kills you.  Make sure you have a CO detector.

Comment: Edited with model...the range is fairly new...only a few months old.

Comment: There is a recall on the Zline RG line of gas ranges. https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2023/ZLINE-Recalls-Gas-Ranges-Due-to-Serious-Risk-of-Injury-or-Death-from-Carbon-Monoxide-Poisoning

Comment: @Legion600 thank you...gave them a call.  The issue they cite is the oven (directed to stop using), but was told burners could still be used while waiting for repair.  It is unclear if the yellow flame is related.  My burners are rather yellow without the oven on....I'll approach it one issue at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the recall (yet to be resolved, though I am registered) had nothing to do with the burner issue.  It turns out that a humidifier, in close proximity to a gas stove, can cause the flames to be more yellow and inconsistent (Zline did help with that issue).